# How to find nth anagram in a given set of time?

Tags: python

I was trying to solve the following question which asks users to find and print the anagram of the given string which occurs at the n{th} position when they are arranged in lexicographical order

```
Sample Input

bcda 20
cbad 5
ydvtrs 268
asfda 32

Sample Output

dacb
adbc
srdvyt
dfasa
```

I tried solving the question in following way:

```
import itertools
a = sorted(set(["".join(perm) for perm in itertools.permutations("abc")]))
a[n]
```

But my code is taking 10s according to them and they are asking me to do in 2s.

They tested it for 20 inputs and all of them gave 10s or nearby that.

Comment: amazon hiring contest :P

Comment: already submitted

Comment: solved both questions?

Comment: yes got shortlisted

Answer (score 1):

You must think through it and go for a less brutal approach.
For example:
- input string is abcd
- I know that after 6 permutations in alphabetical order I'll have results starting with b (bacd will be the first one). It's more of a math question.

Answer (score 0):

You're generating all the possible anagrams sorting and then getting the nth one.

If instead you sort the word first, the anagrams will be already sorted. This way you don't need to sort all the anagrams (you are saving approximately O(n*log(n)), where n is the number of anagrams). You also don't need to run the entire generator, only until it reaches the number you want -- if this number is small this is also a huge gain.

```
import itertools

word = "ydvtrs"
n = 268

sorted_word = ''.join(sorted(word))

print next(itertools.islice(("".join(perm) for perm in itertools.permutations(sorted_word)), n, n + 1))
```

Comment: how can you remove duplicates?

Comment: @mohsinulhaq you're right this doesn't work when the word has duplicates. I didn't realize this was an issue. I'll think about it